# How do I correctly use a path as a parameter?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to change the directory running a bat file with this parameter that will check if this directory exists, make sure it's not a file and change the working directory to it.

```
@ECHO OFF

IF NOT "%1"=="" (
    IF EXIST %1 (
        IF EXIST %1\NUL (
            CD %1
        ) ELSE (
            ECHO Warning: Parameter path is incorrect . . .
        )
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO Warning: Given path does not exist ...
    )
) ELSE (
    ECHO Info: No parameters are given . . .
)

ECHO Info: %CD% is current directory . . .
```

The problem is that when I try to run this with CMD and put the parameter in the quote I get path does not exist error, and if I run this batch file without any parameters it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: You could try changing `IF NOT "%1"=="" (` to `IF NOT "%~1" == ""`, change `IF EXIST %1 (` to `IF EXIST "%~1" (`, change `IF EXIST %1\NUL (` to `IF EXIST "%~1\" (`, and change `CD %1` to `CD /D "%~1"`.

Comment: Modify also the last line to `ECHO Info: "%CD%" is current directory . . .` as otherwise the last command line does not work as expected by you on current directory containing one or more `&` in its full qualified name. Further I recommend to open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `call /?` and read the output help explaining how arguments passed to the batch file can be referenced from within a batch file. Please note that `%0` (argument 0) is always available and is the batch file itself.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to my earlier comments, *(which should solve your reported issue)*, here's an alternative methodology:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
Verify 1 2> NUL
SetLocal EnableExtensions
If ErrorLevel 1 (Echo ERROR: Could not enable extensions.
    GoTo PressClose)
If "%~1" == "" (Echo ERROR: No input argument received.
    GoTo InputError) Else For %%G In ("%~1") Do If "%%~aG" Lss "d" (
    If "%%~aG" GEq "-" (Echo ERROR: Input argument is a file.
        GoTo InputError
    ) Else (Echo ERROR: Your input argument could not be found.
        GoTo InputError))
Rem === Your code here ===
CD /D %1
Set /P "=Your current directory is: %CD%" 0< NUL & Echo(
Rem === Code ends here ===
GoTo PressClose

:InputError
Echo This script requires an existing directory as input.

:PressClose
Echo Please press a key to exit this script.
Pause 1> NUL
Exit /B
```

You would obviously just insert your code in between the two `Rem`arks, I've included two lines there, for the purpose of showing you that it worked, *you are of course free to adjust those as necessary*